# table view cell height isn't applied

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Although I've set the height specifically for the view, the view is still cut off. The prototype cell view height is already set to 300, also the content view and image view (slightly less).

Any idea why? Thanks.

Here are screenshots:

[image: app]

[image: Height configuration]

Comment: Did you try UITableViewDelegate method to set cell height?
`- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;`

Comment: check your code first. If you have added heightForRowAtIndexPath then set size in delegate. otherwise you can heightForRowAtIndexPath for setting row height.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using prototype cells I am assuming you work with dynamic cells.

The row height property of UITableView always will override the cells content height for dynamic cells. So implement the corresponding delegate method `heightForRowAtIndexPath:` or set the row height in the storyboard by setting the row height of your `UITableView`.

Swift 3 delegate method:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 300.0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

set height programatically using delegate method of tableview .

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   return 50//as per your requirement;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you override Cell height? If you didn't by default is 44

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the height of the cell either from the delegate call

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat
```

Here You specify the height of the cell for each indexPath.
If your cell has constant height, than you can set in your viewController typically in `viewDidLoad` at

```
tableView.rowHeight = 300.0
```

If you want the cells height to be calculated by using autolayout, set up your constraints, and do

```
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```